How do honeypot detectors work?
I stumbled upon honeypot detectors and was wondering how they worked.
If I understand correctly, they simulate buy and sell transactions. If the sell goes through, it isn't honeypot, if it doesn't, it is.
My technical question is, how do the simulations actually occur? Does the backend have a local blockchain environment where it deploys the token and checks if and then performs the check? What if the deployer performed a tx after launch that made it honeypot? Does it mean that the local chain environment should replay all txs made by the deployer? And what if the 'activateHoneypot' function was obfuscated so that anyone could call it? Would it mean that ALL token txs should be replayed? And lastly, what if the token contract relies on other contracts? At this point you would have to replay the whole ethereum blockchain, which I think is infeasible considering most of these services are free?
Thanks for the help.

You can find example code here

No idea, but here's how I would do it:

Fork mainnet locally. This way the blockchain has all the needed contracts and has the latest state
Run transactions against the suspected contract and see what happens
If manual research is ok, go through the token code manually

Yes, this is not perfect. Maybe the honeypot is activated only later with some "activateHoneypot" function. Or something else.

Have seen two approaches both are gotten around by the scammer allowing selling until they set some value or zero users balance.

Write a contract that atomically buys and sells in the same transaction returning status, and eth_call the function offchain
Spin up a fork/trace_callMany across blocks.

Problem being it is only gonna catch the hardcoded issues.
The user can buy and sell until they actually buy, then the contract owner toggles a mapping on their address and they are blocked, those transactions will auto fire out blocks after they purchase.
Anecdotally, when looking into creating one of these tools for a dex I contributed at previously, it didn't seem like there was a reliable way to catch many of the scams, coupled with the cost of running the service and keeping it up from ddos attacks etc didn't seem viable, especially when conflated with how absolute users interoperate those detectors to be.
Real evaluation of a token contracts legitimacy takes more than spinning up a fork and simulating the state changes.
That said, they are wonderful tools to be included as part of a holistic process, and to save time in looking through the most egregious examples.
